# How to merge both, mutable and immutable worlds?

Tags: c

In the ideal world, systems are designed using immutable data structures. However, when you dive deeper into lower levels of abstractions, you realize that at some point a library written in C is being used to performs some tricks that merge the unmutable with the mutable.

Now, I am not intrested in whether or not I should mutate my data. Instead, how do you design libraries and tools that help merging both, the mutable and unmutable?

For instance, how do you design a system that serves as an interface where work that need mutable behavior for performance reasons can be delegated from the unmutable world?

Is there any book that talks about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "help merging both"?  I don't understand what you mean by "merge".  I don't know what you mean by "can be delegated from the unmutable world".   Also, the question sounds very broad, and it may be difficult to answer in this form.  Do you have a specific problem or task you are trying to solve?

Comment: "In the ideal world, systems are designed using immutable data structures": if you restrict yourself to immutable things, what use is any program ? In the real world, program state continuously evolves and data is updated. That's the purpose of computers.